# Issues converting to number

Tags: javascript, math

I am having issues with arithmatic and converting to numbers. I think.

I need to get the total width of an element. In this case it is a button, and I want to divide it by 2.

```
  var $buttonWidth = parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true));
  console.log($.isNumeric($buttonWidth));
  console.log(isNaN($buttonWidth));

  console.log($buttonWidth);
  $buttonWidth / 2;

  console.log($buttonWidth);
```

The first log is returning true, the second is returning false, the third is returning the total width of the element and the fourth log is also returning the total width of the log. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What do you expect in output?

Comment: I'm expecting the fourth log to be the third log divide by two.

Comment: `$buttonWidth = $buttonWidth / 2;`  You're not reassigning the result back to the variable. width / 2 is just an expression, it wont change the original variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the new value to $buttonWidth.

```
$buttonWidth = $buttonWidth / 2;
```

or

```
$buttonWidth /= 2;
```